# How to calculate the Lateral in this FC using the formula: "height/TAN(RADIANS(48.5)" would usually do in excel, but how to do using field calculator

Tags: python, arcmap

[image]

I want to use the height field already in my FC to calculate the Lateral using the following formula from excel `height/TAN(RADIANS(48.5)`

I just don't know how to write the python script in ArcMap to perform the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below python command in the ArcMap field calculator:

```
!Height! /math.tan( 48.5)
```

[image]

**The resulting values in the field:**

[image]

**To cross verify:**

[image]